# Laravel 5.4 Sentinel session does not persist

Tags: php, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'],'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Ministries\Http\Controllers'], function () {

    Route::get('ny/ministries/index', array('uses' => 'MinistriesController@getIndex', 'as' => 'admin.ministries.index'));
    Route::get('ny/ministries/data', array('uses' => 'MinistriesController@getData', 'as' => 'admin.ministries.data'));
    Route::get('ny/ministries/show/{id}', array('uses' => 'MinistriesController@getView', 'as' => 'admin.ministries.view'));
    Route::post('ny/ministries/store/', array('uses' => 'MinistriesController@postNew', 'as' => 'admin.ministries.new'));
    Route::post('ny/ministries/bulk/', array('uses' => 'MinistriesController@postBulkUpload', 'as' => 'admin.ministries.post'));
});
```

Authentication works fine however when I try Sentinel::check(); the value returned for the currently logged in user is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the protected middleware array Kernel.php in the Http Folder

> \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

and then comment out below since you are not using laravels default auth function

> \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class

Comment: Thanks for this solution !! You have saved my day !! :)